# One altitude, one bisector and one median are equal implies equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle such that the lenghts of the $A$-angle-bisector, the $B$-median and the $C$-altitude are equal. Prove that $ABC$ is equilateral.

I was only able to show that $AB$ is the smallest side -- this follows from the $C$-altitude being the largest one. I cannot figure out a proper chain of inequalities to strengthen this argument, though I think it might be useful to use that from one vertex the angle bisector is always positioned between the median and the altitude.

Any help appreciated!

Update (thanks for the comments): Treat $ABC$ to be **acute** and if possible, try to give a synthetic proof (angle chasing, congruences, etc.)

Comment: Is this true? Some symbol-crunching in *Mathematica* gives me that a $1$-$4.1989$-$5.1334$ triangle is such that the altitude to the $1$ side, the angle bisector to the $4.1989$ side, and the median to $5.1334$ side all have the same length, $1.6515$. (All values approximate here.) I could have mis-entered something, but a GeoGebra sketch with 10-decimal-place accuracy shows that this is at least plausible. (I used [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) to get formulas for the median and angle bisector.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be the common $A$-bisector/$B$-median/$C$-altitude.

In its role as the $A$-bisector, $x$ satisfies (by [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) and the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem))
$$b^2\,\frac{ac}{b+c}+c^2\,\frac{ab}{b+c}=a\left(x^2+\frac{a^2bc}{(b+c)^2}\right)\;\to\;x^2(b+c)^2=bc(a+b+c)(-a+b+c) \tag{1}$$

As the $B$-median (again by Stewart, or [Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem)),
$$c^2\;\frac{b}{2}+a^2\;\frac{b}{2} = b \left(x^2+\frac{b^2}{4}\right)\quad\to\quad
4x^2 = 2a^2-b^2+2c^2 \tag{2}$$

As the $C$-altitude (invoking [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)),
$$\frac12cx=|\triangle ABC|\quad\to\quad4c^2x^2=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) \tag{3}$$

The non-linear system $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ turns out to be quartic. Throwing it into *Mathematica* for numerical solution, and discarding non-positive values, gives two options:

> $$(a,b,c,x) = \left(1,1,1,\frac12\sqrt{3}\right)\qquad (a,b,c,x) = \left(1,  1.2225\ldots, 0.2381\ldots, 0.3933\ldots\right) \tag{$\star$}$$

(The values in my comment to the question correspond to taking $c=1$.) The first solution is, of course, the equilateral triangle; the second is obtuse:

[image]

So, if we restrict ourselves to *acute* triangles, the equilateral becomes the only solution. $\square$